# How do I fix "Clock getDataFormat the getSystemString failed"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, logcat

I created a button Bluetooth. 
When I click on the button it should begin a new activity, instead the app close.

I looked in the **Logcat** and I see :

> W/HwLauncher: Clock getDataFormat the getSystemString failed.

```
    //in Main 
    bluetooth = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bluetooth);
    bluetooth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Device Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), bluetooth.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Of course it did. your class is named the same as your variable.

Comment: I changed the variable it's still not working